# How can I convert my appsettings.json section to an object?

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-5

I have an **appsettings.json** that looks like this:

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*",
    "SearchExclusions": {
        "Classifications": {
            "title": "My First Title",
            "entries": [ "ALPHA", "BETA" ]
        },
        "SubjectContains": {
            "title": "My Second Title",
            "entries": [ "GAMMA", "DELTA", "EPSILON", "ZETA", "ETA", "THETA", "IOTA", "KAPPA" ]
        }
    }
}
```

My **.RAZOR** component looks like this:

```
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
<h1> My Component </h1>
@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // This does not work.
        var searchExclusionsObject = Configuration.GetSection("SearchExclusions").Get<SearchExclusions>();

        // This also does not work.
        var searchExclusionsObject = Configuration.Get<SearchExclusions>();
    }

    private class SearchExclusions
    {
        private Classifications classifications { get; set; }
        private SubjectContains subjectContains { get; set; }
    }

    private class Classifications
    {
        private String title { get; set; }
        private String[] entries { get; set; }
    }

    private class SubjectContains
    {
        private String title { get; set; }
        private String[] entries { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your properties on SearchExclusions and other child classes are private, they need to be public.

Comment: Well, don't I feel stupid? Thank you so much! I thought since everything was in the same class (or .RAZOR component) that private would be accessible to all. I guess not. Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, it's just the accessibility of your properties that needs to be changed from Private to Public

Comment: I thought since everything was in the same class (or .RAZOR component) that private would be accessible to all.

Comment: Yeah, even if it's in the same component/file, it is still called outside the *actual class*, so it should be made public.
Anther tip if you want, when creating classes to use it as mapping with the Json configuration file, or any Json or XML .. you can use one of the tools/website to  do this, you give them the JSON/XML and you get all the classes you need. like this one
https://json2csharp.com/